# How to change color or customize header arrow for expandableRow in Mui Datatable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a MUI data table with the expandable rows Option. I have also enabled the ExpandAll button on the header row which displays an arrow in the title row which is similar to the arrows in all the rows. This gets confusing for the user. SO i want to change the header arrow to a different color by overriding its properties or adding some text below it. However I am not able to find any documentation to change its properties. What do i do?

```
   options={{
                download: false,
                expandableRows: true,
                expandableRowsOnClick: true,

                renderExpandableRow: (rowData, rowMeta) => {}
}}
```

The arrow that I want to change is highlighted in the image.

[image]

**EDIT:**
[Example](https://github.com/gregnb/mui-datatables/blob/master/examples/expandable-rows/index.js)
I have seen the following example but this customizes the arrows for the individual rows and not for the arrow which is the column header. How do i modify that? what is the classname for that single component?

Answer (score 0):

Do you try this variant from documentation?
https://mui.com/material-ui/react-table/#CollapsibleTable.js

They have `Collapse` component for hide table inside the row and

```
<TableCell>
   <IconButton
      aria-label="expand row"
      size="small"
      onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
     >
       {open ? <KeyboardArrowUpIcon /> : <KeyboardArrowDownIcon />}
     </IconButton>
</TableCell>
```

And you can change color of color using, for example `style={{fill: custom_color}}`

Comment: Hey, this means I would have to switch the table and the data flow to feed the row information. It would take mu ch longer. Is there a way to override the property to add color to the header component arrow directly?

Comment: Hello! 
I just remembered one props - `sx` [here it the link](https://mui.com/system/getting-started/the-sx-prop/) 
I think [this example](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/how-to-customize/#DevTools.tsx) can help you. They provide the ability to use CSS selectors and select the required classes.